# python called from powershell loop using delay

Tags: python, powershell, loops

How can I call python via powershell using loop and delay for each call

like:
in powershell:

```
for(i=0;i++;i<72){
  python pythonFile.py $arg
  delay(10 secounds)

}
```

in pythonFile:

```
import sys
Say(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a delay of 10 seconds in Powershell, use `sleep 10`

The correct loop structure as per the requirement would be:

```
for($i=0;$i -le 72;$i++){
    python pythonFile.py $arg
    sleep 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `time.sleep(10)` somewhere in your Python file instead.

This will keep the delaying step within Python itself and will be easier to manage, hopefully.

Your pythonFile.py would then look something like:

```
import sys
import time

Say(sys.argv)
time.sleep(10)
```